# When I delete a range of cells (K2:K18) getting an debug message

Tags: vba, excel

I am stuck up with one of the VBA code. My requirement is when the user selects the option "Resigned" in K row from the data validation provided he should get a pop up messages as "Please provide the user's Last Working Date in DD-MM-YYYY format on column L2". Here L2 is just an example.

But, when I hit the delete key by selecting the range K2:K18 getting an message "Runtime error 13, type mismatch"

Please help to resolve this :(

Following is my code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Intersect(Target, Range("K:K")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
If Target.Value <> "Resigned" Then Exit Sub
MsgBox "Please provide the user's Last Working Date in DD-MM-YYYY format on " & Target.Offset(0, 1).Address

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check `If Target.Cells.Count <> 1` and handle appropriately.

In your case, you're causing the `_Change` event to take the `Target` argument as `Range("K2:K18")` which is an array, hence the type mismatch error.

Here is a simple case which just aborts the procedure if `Target` is more than 1 cell range:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Conditions which cause the event to terminate early, avoid errors
    If Target.Cells.Count <> 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Intersect(Target, Range("K:K")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    If Target.Value = "Resigned" Then 
        MsgBox "Please provide the user's Last Working Date in DD-MM-YYYY format on " & Target.Offset(0, 1).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
        Application.GoTo Target.Offset(0,1)
    End If
End Sub
```

Or, to handle multiple cell range, you could do something like:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Conditions which cause the event to terminate early, avoid errors
    Dim rng As Range, cl As Range, msg as String
    Set rng = Intersect(Target, Range("K:K"))
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    For Each cl in rng
        If cl.Value = "Resigned" Then 
            msg = msg & vbCRLF & cl.Offset(0,1).Address(False,False)
        End If
    Next
    If msg <> vbNullString Then
        MsgBox "Please provide the user's Last Working Date in DD-MM-YYYY format on " & vbCrlf & msg
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: One more thing if possible, the message box when pops up the message is displayed as "Please provide the user's Last Working Date in DD-MM-YYYY format on $L$2"

Comment: can we avoid the $ sign

Comment: @Sanoj use `.Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)` to omit the $ from the rows & columns respectively.

Comment: Ohh.. David you are great!!! :) really it worked amazing. I am new to the forum don't know how to mark the answer as "Accepted".